# Left and right alignment of text in one row

Tags: wpf, xaml, alignment, dockpanel

I want to put two labels in one row, the first being aligned to the left border, the second to the right.

Like here:

[image]

Here is my XAML try:

```
<Window x:Class="MyTestNamespace.MyXAML"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006">
    <DockPanel>
        <Label Content="left text" DockPanel.Dock="Left"></Label>
        <Label Content="right text" DockPanel.Dock="Right"></Label>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

But instead I get this:

[image]

1. What I am doing wrong with the DockPanel?
2. How can I achieve the design of the first picture (not necessarily with DockPanel)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used the dockpanel correct but you need align the the label content to right. Try this

```
<DockPanel>
        <Label Content="left text" DockPanel.Dock="Left"></Label>
        <Label Content="right text" DockPanel.Dock="Right" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"></Label>
    </DockPanel>
```